# the app. is not getting installed on the device, console generates errors

Tags: android, eclipse

When I tried to install my app on the device, the console generates the below posted message.
In my device the developers option is enabled and I also cleaned and re-built the workspace.
please help my to solve this problem

Console Output:

```
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] ------------------------------
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] Android Launch!
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] The launch will only sync the application package  
on the device!
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] Performing sync
[2014-07-26 11:30:12 - CompassTest00] Uploading CompassTest00.apk onto device    
'4df74a35687230a1'
[2014-07-26 11:30:13 - CompassTest00] Installing CompassTest00.apk...
[2014-07-26 11:30:22 - CompassTest00] Success!
[2014-07-26 11:30:22 - CompassTest00] \CompassTest00\bin\CompassTest00.apk installed on  
device
[2014-07-26 11:30:22 - CompassTest00] Done!
```

ManifestFile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.compasstest00"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.compasstest00.AndroidSensors"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_sensors" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly declare your main activity in the `Manifest.xml` file, something like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.compasstest00.AndroidSensors"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_sensors">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You have the activity already declared, but is missing the `LAUNCHER` intent filter, this is what the log is telling you. This `intent-filter` tells Android which of your activities is the main one (you can have several activities in one application)

Answer (score -1):

When I first tried using my phone (device) instead of an emulator, I too experienced this type of behavior.  Two things I did that fixed it were:
(1) downloaded the usb driver for my phone.  for example i have a Samsung Galaxy SIII.  I googled it and found its usb driver and downloaded and installed it on my laptop.
(2) I also restarted the adb by issuing the following commands:

adb kill-server

adb start-server

if you change views from the normal view to the DDMS view you should see your device show up there is everything is working correctly.

Comment: -1, this has nothing to do with the problem. It is clear that Android cannot find "launcher" activity because it's not declared in the manifest.

Comment: It looks like your original question was answered, but to answer your question to me, you would type it in a cmd window.  If you find your app is not showing up on your phone at some point and it is not showing up in the DDMS view, give that a try (for future reference).